# hardhat-deploy: ProviderError: The method evm_snapshot does not exist/is not available

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I'm trying to run a test with hardhat, and have it deploy my deployments/fixtures with the command:

```
npx hardhat test --network rinkeby --deploy-fixture
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

`ProviderError: The method evm_snapshot does not exist/is not available`

I have a `deploy` folder containing all my methods to deploy, and `npx hardhat deploy --network rinkeby` works great.

What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fixture functionality currently doesn't work for testnets. If you want to run your tests on a testnet, you'll first have to deploy the contracts, and then run your tests.

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes your fixture setup looks something like this (?):

```
await deployments.fixture(contractName);
```

You can define a function `isLocalEnv` as follows.

```
function isLocalEnv(envName: string) {
  return !!({
    hardhat: true,
    localhost: true,
  } as Record<string, true>)[envName];
}
```

Then, wherever you set up the fixture, import `network` from `hardhat`, and use `isLocalEnv` to safeguard against the potentially-useless fixture init. Aka.

```
if (isLocalEnv(network.name)) {
  await deployments.fixture(contractName);
}
```